# How do I stop Blend 2.5 June Preview replacing Canvas.ZIndex with Panel.ZIndex on SL1.0 XAML?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, blend

I have a Silverlight 1.0 application that I edit with Blend 2.5.  Whenever I touch a `UIElement` in the designer that has a Canvas attribute such as `Canvas.ZIndex="1"`, when it updates the XAML, it changes the Canvas prefix to Panel, leaving `Panel.ZIndex="1"`, causing the page to fail to load.

How do I make it stop the insanity!?!

I have uninstalled 2.5 and reinstalled an older Blend 2 preview and that was better, but then compatibility with VS2k8 was not as good, and I'm also working on some SL2.0 projects from time to time, as well as WPF apps, both of which I prefer Blend 2.5 for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a reported bug in 2.5,

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/blend/thread/db02b75c-922e-4de1-8943-bd525d9862c0/

Their suggested workaround is to use 2.0 for SL1. Still, I expect there will be a new version of Blend released fairly shortly, since SL2 is likely to be released around PDC this year (end of October).